# Find the number of the continuous function between this topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let the $(X,T) = \{ \{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3,4\} ,\{1,2,3,4\}, \{1,2,5\}, X, \phi       \}$ on $X = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$

Find the number of the continuous function $f: (X, T) \to (X,T)$ satisfying the $f(2)=2, f(3) =3$

Since the $f(\bar A) \subset \bar f(A)$ for the continuous function $f$, $f(5) \in \{2,5\}$ and $f(4) \in \{3,4\}$ considering the $A =$ $\{2,5\}$ or $\{3,4\}$ each cases. Plus $1$ is the isolated point, $f$ is always continuous at $1$. Therefore $f(1) \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$. So my answer is $2\times 2\times 5 =20$. But the answer was $4$. It said $f$ is continuous only for the $f(1)=1$. Why the answer is $4$? How can I derive it? Plus, What the point did I have a mistake?

Comment: I assume that you mean: Let $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $T=\{\{1\},\{1,2\},...\}$ be a topology on $X$?

Comment: @OliverHouse, Yes. That is exactly what I meant.

Comment: The answer 4 is also wrong....

Answer (score 1):

It's IMO handiest to use the inverse image of open is open definition for continuity first:

If $1 \in f[X]$, we know that $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ must be open and cannot contain $2$ or $3$, and so then $f^{-1}[\{1\}] = \{1\}$ and $f(1)=1$. This is case one.

If $1 \notin f[X]$, of course $f^{-1}[\{1\}]=\emptyset$ which is open, as it must be. This is case two.

Going on in in case one, we know then that $f(x)=x$ for $x=1,2,3$. What more can we say? $f^{-1}[\{1,3,4\}]$ must be open as well and contains $\{1,3\}$ as a subset already. We can only add one point to it by mapping to $4$ and the only open subset that has two or three elements and has $\{1,3\}$ as a subset is $\{1,3,4\}$ again. It follows that $f(4)=4$ as well. Now $f^{-1}[\{1,2,5\}]$ has two or three elements and $\{1,2\}$ as a subset. So either it's $\{1,2\}$ and $5 \notin f[X]$, or it's $\{1,2,5\}$ and $f(5)=5$ and $f=1_X$ (which always is continuous).

So what in case 1 if $5 \notin f[X]$? Where can $5$ map to? If to $1$ it would make $f^{-1}[\{1\}=\{1,5\}$ which is not open, so that cannot be. $2$ is similarly refuted by $f^{-1}[\{1,2\}]=\{1,2,5\}$, $3$ by $f^{-1}[\{1,3,4\}]=\{1,3,4,5\}$, while mapping to $4$ gives $f^{-1}[\{1,3,4\}=\{1,3,4,5\}$, also not open. So this subcase is in fact a dead end.

Conclusion: case 1 leads to a unique function $1_X$, always continuous anyway.

Now to case 2: $1 \notin f[X]$, initially overseen by markvs' answer.

We know that $2 \in f^{-1}[\{1,2\}] = f^{-1}[\{2\}]$ and also $1 \notin f^{-1}[\{1,2\}]$. There is no open set that contains $2$ but not $1$ so this case also immediately terminates.

A unique but boring function it is.

You see that this is quite tedious, I seem to recall from a paper on finite spaces that there is a more efficient algorithm to do this kind of problems by looking at the specialisation order or minimal neighbourhoods.

Comment: This is a copy of my answer posted several hours earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is $1$. Only the identity function satisfies all conditions.

It is better to look at preimages of open sets. The preimage of every open set must be open.

The preimage of
$\{1\}$ must be open, but it does not contain $2$ or $3$. So only  $1$ can go to $1$.

The preimage of $\{1,2\}$ must be open, it contains both $1$ and $2$ but cannot contain $3$.  So it may be either $\{1,2\}$ or $\{1,2,5\}$. Thus the preimage of $2$ is either $\{2\}$ or $\{2,5\}$ - two cases.

Case 1. Suppose that the preimage of $2$ is $\{2\}$. The preimage of $\{1,2,5\}$ must contain $1,2$, cannot contain $3$. So it is $\{1,2,5\}$. Thus the preimage of $5$ is $\{5\}$. Then the preimage of $\{1,3,4\}$ must contain $1,3$ but cannot contain $2, 5$. So the preimage of $\{1,3,4\}$ is $\{1,3,4\}$ and $f(4)=4$. Thus in this case $f$ is the identity function.

Case 2. Suppose that the preimage of $2$ is $\{2,5\}$. So $f(5)=2$.
The preimage of $\{1,2,5\}$ must contain $1,2$, cannot contain $3$. That preimage cannot be $\{1,2,5\}$ because $f(5)=2$. There are no other options, so this case is impossible.

**Edit**: As @HennoBrandsma noticed I have not considered the case when the preimage of $1$ is empty. In that case the preimage of $\{1,2\}$ must contain $2$ but cannot contain $3$, so it is  $\{1,2,5\}$. But then  $f(5)=1$ which is impossible because the preimage of $1$ is empty.

Comment: I don't understand the analysis in case 2. Why can't the preimage of $\{1,2,5\}$ be $\{1,2,5\}$?

Comment: @Snaw: If it was $\{1,2,5\}$ then $f(5)=5$, but $f(5)=2$.

Comment: I must be missing something. I realize that $f(5)=2$, but why would the preimage of $\{1,2,5\}$ being $\{1,2,5\}$ necessitate $f(5)=5$? We can have that the preimage of $\{5\}$ is the empty set and then the preimage of $\{1,2,5\}$ can be the same as the preimage of $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @Shaw: If the preimage of $\{1,2,5\}$ is $\{1,2,5\}$, then $f$ must map $1,2$ or $5$ to $5$. But $f(1)=1, f(2)=2$, so $f(5)$ must be $5$.

Comment: If $f(1)=1,f(2)=2,f(5)=2$, and if there is no $x$ for which $f(x)=5$, then $f^{-1}(\{1,2,5\})=\{1,2,5\}$.

Comment: $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ could also be empty! Then your analysis falls short.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: The result stays the same, see the edit.